# How to display input string as asterisk(*) in LEX programming?

Tags: compiler-construction, lex

I am creating a program that checks if the password entered by the user is valid. I have written the code like this:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int upper=0, lower=0, dig=0, spChar=0, length=0;
%}

%%
[a-z] {lower++; length++;}
[A-Z] {upper++;length++;}
[0-9] {dig++;length++;}
[!@#$%&^*_()+=.,?;:] {spChar++;length++;}
%%

int main(){
printf("\nEnter your password. Your password should have:\n");
printf("\t1.Minimum 8 characters\n\t2.Atleast 1 uppercase character");
printf("\n\t3.Atleast 1 lowercase character\n\t4. Atleast 1 special character\n\t5. Atleast 1 digit\n");
printf("\nEnter a password:\n");
yylex();

if(length>8 && upper!=0 && lower!=0 && dig!=0 && spChar!=0){
printf("\nHURRAY!! YOUR PASSWORD IS STRONG\n");
}
else{
printf("\nYOUR PASSWORD IS WEAK :( TRY AGAIN!\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

'''

I want all the characters that I give as input to the program to be displayed as asterisks(*).
Example:
Enter the password: TOM
I want to display it like this:
Enter the password: ***
Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: This code doesn't display *anything* except the prompts and the success/failure messages. But using *lex(1)* for this is considerable overkill. You could probably do the whole thing with a single regular expression.

Comment: This problem is not related to lex at all. By default your application/command-line window will be in line-editing mode which means that it will echo the pressed keys and do some very basic editing until you press enter and when you do the entire line is fed to your program. To do what you want you need to switch your command line window to non-echoing character based reading. How this is done depends on your operating system.

Comment: @Johan, I am using Ubuntu 20 LTS.  Is there any way to do so? Please suggest.